# what is hectoPascAltimeter

Tags: air, weather, weather-api, pressure

what is hectoPascAltimeter, is it air pressure in mbars?

check http://ws.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherXML?lat=43&lng=-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pascal as the SI pressure measurement:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(unit)

"In everyday life, the pascal is perhaps best known from meteorological barometric pressure reports, where it occurs in the form of hectopascals (1 hPa ≡ 100 Pa"

Comment: i wanted Atmospheric pressure in millibars, does anywhere in xml has it? how can i get it? or how can i convert it? sorry i have very less knowledge on weather, but i need it for my project

Comment: From that wikipedia article, "Standard atmospheric pressure is 101,325 Pa = 101.325 kPa = 1013.25 hPa = 1013.25 mbar = 760 Torr". Using that, you should be able to do the conversion from hPa to mBar.

Comment: im sorry, im very dump, but can you tell me how can i calculate hpa to mbar? it would probally be easy for you and really helpful for me.

Comment: @Eric 1013.25 hPa = 1013.25 mbar - so I'd assume that the answer is indeed yes 1 hectoPascal == 1 millibar.  Google confirms:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=1+hectopascal+to+millibars&aq=f&aqi=h1&oq=

Comment: Looks like... I feel silly for not noticing the 1 to 1 relationship when I copy-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [QNH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNH) in hectopascals... so it's related to the barometric pressure, but not quite what you want; it's the altimeter setting to get an airplane's altimeter reading the actual height of the runway.  Not useful for much other than aviation, because there are safety related corrections in there that are hard to reverse.